# Format seconds.milliseconds into minutes:seconds.milliseconds

Tags: libreoffice-calc

How could I go about having a cell where the display shows a time format, but is edited in raw seconds and milliseconds?

I want to have a cell where when clicked on and a value typed, the user types say 91.5, and on the value being updated, the cell displays say 00:01:31.5 or just 1:31.5.

I think it needs to divide the raw seconds by 86400 (seconds in a day) in the format, but can't see how it would be possible to do that.

**Clarification 01/05/2018:**

Ideally the cell being edited and cell displaying the value would be the same cell.

Answer (score 1):

Format ->Number Format->general

```
=b2*86400
```

[image: Convert to seconds]

Going in reverse:

```
=b2/86400
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks @cybernard, well constructed answer! This solution looks though like it always needs two cells to do the job. Ideally in your example when you click on B2 and start typing a number in seconds, the string "91.5", then hit <enter>, cell B2 will update itself with the correct format, without needing cell C2. Perhaps that's what you're showing me and I've missed something?

Comment: @JCollins You do need 2 cells.  If you wrote a macro you could enter values, highlight the cells, and write the macro to act all on the selected cells.